# Lua programming - How to email multiple attachments?

Tags: email, lua, smtp, email-attachments

I tried sending multiple attachments to email address using SMTP server and mime.lua. I'm trying to get all pdfs in the folder but I'm getting nil value and receiving empty emails. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
local mime = require 'mime'
local name = {}
function email()
    local i = 0 --counter for for loop
    for FileName, FileInfo in os.fs.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/*.pdf') do
        i = i+1
        trace(FileName)
        name[i] = FileName --populate name with FileName 
        print(name[i])
        trace(FileInfo)
    end   
end


function main()
    email()
    local Results = mime.send{--dont think i need this
        server='*************', 
        username='********', 
        password='***********',
        from='*****************', 
        to={'************************'},
        header={['Subject']='Test Subject'}, 
        body='Test Email Body', 
        use_ssl='try',
        attachments=name,
        trace(name)
    }
end
```